# Can I import DXF files,exported from Gerber? The DXF file is AAMA file

Tags: import

I am trying to import DXF files exported from Gerber but it is not importing the content.
I used following settings:
- Replace scene
- Remove duplicates, Limit 1.00
- Merge All
- Thick ON
- Codec- ASCII

Do I need to choose a different settings?

Comment: Is the Outliner showing a completely empty scene? Could you privide a sample file? Blender should be able to import DXF files, but maybe that format has peculiar characteristics...

Comment: I remember having problems getting DXF files into recent versions of Blender. Try using Blender 2.49b because I believe it has a different DXF importer - one that was not maintained by the developer in versions beyond that. Again, going from memory here and I could be wrong, but give it a try.